# over ssh -X : DISPLAY is not set

Tags: ssh, debian, debian-squeeze

I try connect over ssh with

```
 ssh -X user@host
```

but I get

```
$ xterm
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: xterm:  DISPLAY is not set

$ echo $DISPLAY
# ... nothing
```

In my sshd_config I have

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

## EDIT

In `/var/log/auth.log` I get

```
 sshd[7396]: error: Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket.
```

Comment: What is the output of $ echo $DISPLAY

Comment: Is an X server running on your source? Before you ssh anywhere else, `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: @Andres with `echo $DISPLAY` I get nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I dont have `lo`, I fix the problem added to file `/etc/network/interfaces` the lines

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: After all the suggestions of "AddressFamily inet" or "install xauth" etc, this was the actual fix for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If ipv6 is causing an issue, add this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart ssh.

```
AddressFamily inet
```

Comment: I try add `AddressFamily inet` and restart `sshd` but get the same, and try `ssh -4` to force ipv4, but nothing

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the xauth package is installed on BOTH machines

Comment: yes, `xauth` is installed in both machines

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the display value prior to logging in, like:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

Then ssh in:

```
ssh -Y user@host
```

if it's not working using

```
ssh -X user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

Run xhost + and then, the ssh command.